# Struts checkbox validation javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp, checkbox, struts2

I'm using Struts, this is checkbox in JSP file

```
<th class="input required">Check Box</th>
    <td class="input" colspan="4">
       <html:checkbox property="chkb1" value="1" styleId="chkb_opt01"></html:checkbox> 
        <label for="chkb_opt01" class="width80">checkbox1</label>
       <html:checkbox property="chkb2" value="5" styleId="chkb_opt05"></html:checkbox> 
        <label for="chkb_opt05" class="width80">checkbox2</label>
    </td>
```

I've tried to write JavaScript carry out validation for checkbox. At least one checkbox checked.

Comment: Where is your javascript??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the source of the html in any browser. Or, If you can use firebug in firefox, dragonfly in opera, Developer tools by IE and Chrome and   inspect the element. The custom tags whether it is struts tags or any other, generate HTML which is same as normal HTML.

e.g.

```
<html:checkbox property="chkb1" value="1" styleId="chkb_opt01"></html:checkbox>
```

Will converted to

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chkb1" id="chkb_opt01"></input>
```

For validation using javascript,you can either use name or id attribute.

e.g.

Using name attribute

```
   if(document.getElementsByName("chkb1")[0].checked)
   {
       alert("This is checked.. ");
   }
   else
   {
       alert("Oops!!! You are not checked") 
   }
```

Using id attribute

```
   if(document.getElementById("chkb_opt01").checked)
   {
       alert("This is checked.. ");
   }
   else
   {
       alert("Oops!!! You are not checked") 
   }
```